# How to use python to run php

Tags: python, php

I have a php script that runs well.

```
<?php

include_once "lib/m2x.php";

$api_key = "API KEY";
$feed_id = "FEED ID";
$stream  = "something";

$m2x = new M2X($api_key);

$data = array(
  'value' => 992.23,
  'unit'  => array('label' => 'Celsius')
);
$response = $m2x->feeds()->update_stream('FEED ID', $stream, $data);

?>
```

However, I want to be able to update the 'value' variable from my raspberry pi, then rerun the script to send that data. Is there a way in python to update this variable (getting data in from GPIO) then run the php script?

Thanks,
Mihir

Comment: M2X has a Python library, it would be much easier to just rewrite the script in Python.

Comment: what stops you from `sudo apt-get install php5` and then running your script on Raspberry?

Comment: @DanNixon thanks! I just noticed that they have a python library. I'll see if I can use that instead. It'll probably save me a lot of time :)

Comment: @lenik The problem with that is I need to continously change a variable within the script, then re-run it.

Answer (score 7):

You can call the php Script using python's os.system:

```
import os
value = 992.23
os.system("php /path/to/your/file.php %s"%(value))
```

in you php file, just specify the value as given per command line:

```
'value' => $argv[1],
```

Comment: Did it work? If so, consider accepting the answer.